# Image disappears in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I never use jQuery before so I ask a friend to help me with some small project I'm working on, I wanted to load different pictures when you hover over buttons, and you can see how that works on [our site](http://studiospartacus.com/index1.html). It works fine with FF and Opera, I have tested in Chrome as well, but when I try it from my machine locally it works great, but as soon as I put it on the server the pictures in Chrome and IE start to disappear when you change buttons. Here's the code I use:

```
<div id="wraper">
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="left">
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#left').hover(
                        function(){
                            $('#nav').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/serbia.png)'});
                        },
                        function(){
                            $('#nav').css({"backgroundImage" : "url(img/inactivebutton.png)"});
                        }
                    );
                });

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#right').hover(
                        function(){
                            $('#nav').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/english.png)'});
                        },
                        function(){
                            $('#nav').css({"backgroundImage" : "url(img/inactivebutton.png)"});
                        }
                    );
                });
            </script>
            <a href="index_sr.html" ></a>
        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <a href="index_en.html" ></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what's in the server error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue with `Jquery`. It's natural process because when you `hover` over the link then it send an new other `HTTPS` request to the server. It's good if your use css `sprite` images for this.

Read this article for this http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

You're using the CSS function weird...

look here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

so change it in this way:

```
 $('#nav').css('background-image','url(img/serbia.png)');
```

etc.

Comment: when i put , dw says there is code error and it dosent work at all

Answer (score 0):

Your images have to load, so when you are rolling over them, there is a small 'glitch' where the image is loading up.

Try preloading the images, as explained here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

e: At least, thats how I've interpreted your problem. When you say they 'disappear', do you mean permanently?

Comment: nope, will u please go to http://studiospartacus.com/index1.html with chrome or ie and you will see what im talking about

Comment: i also try to change backgroundImage to background-image and it still works when i test it locally but soon i test it on server its buggy, picture all the time load when u change buttons

Comment: It is to do with it needing to be reloaded every time. It takes time to swap the image as JavaScript isn't instant. try using CSS to make the swap instead of JS.

Comment: can u please help me how to use css instead of jquery

Answer (score 0):

Separt the pics 
as

- leftActiveHelmet.png  ----left helmet
- rightActiveHelmet.png ----right helmet
- inactiveHelmet.png   ---inactive helmet
- inactivebutton.png   ---inactive button
- leftActivebutton.png  --active left button
- rightActivebutton.png  ---active right button

  ```
      <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#left').hover(

     function(){
      $('#logo').css({"backgroundImage" : "url(img/leftActiveHelmet.png)"});
      $('#left').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/leftActivebutton.png)'});
      },
      function(){
      $('#logo').css({"backgroundImage" : "url(img/inactiveHelmet.png)"});
      $('#left').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/inactivebutton.png)'});
      }
      );

      $('#right').hover(
      function(){
      $('#logo').css({"backgroundImage" : "url(img/rightActiveHelmet.png)"});
      $('#left').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/rightactivebutton.png)'});
      },
      function(){
      $('#logo').css({"backgroundImage" : "url(img/inactiveHelmet.png)"});
      $('#right').css({'background-image' : 'url(img/inactivebutton.png)'});

      }
      );

  });


  </script>
  <div id="logo"></div><div id="nav"><a id="left" href="index_sr.html" ></a><a id="right" href="index_en.html" ></a></div>
  ```

  You have to put the CSS code too.
  logo is the helment.
  nav is the div for the button.
  left and right are buttons